# helm: how to remove newline after toYaml function

Tags: kubernetes-helm

From official documentation:
When the template engine runs, it removes the contents inside of {{ and }}, but it leaves the remaining whitespace exactly as is. The curly brace syntax of template declarations can be modified with special characters to tell the template engine to chomp whitespace. {{- (with the dash and space added) indicates that whitespace should be chomped left, while -}} means whitespace to the right should be consumed.

But I try all variations with no success. Have anyone solution how to place yaml inside yaml? I don't want to use `range`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: app
  labels:
    app: app
spec:
  containers:
  - name: app
    image: image
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: test
        name: test
    resources:
{{ toYaml .Values.pod.resources | indent 6 }}
  volumes:
  - name: test
    emptyDir: {}
```

when I use this code without `-}}` it's adding a newline:

```
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: 128Mi
      requests:
        cpu: 20m
        memory: 64Mi

  volumes:
  - name: test
    emptyDir: {}
```

but when I use `-}}` it's concate with another position.

```
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: 100m
    memory: 128Mi
  requests:
    cpu: 20m
    memory: 64Mi
  volumes: <- shoud be in indent 2
- name: test
  emptyDir: {}
```

values.yaml is

```
pod:
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: 20m
      memory: 64Mi
    limits:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 128Mi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below variant is correct:

```
{{ toYaml .Values.pod.resources | indent 6 }}
```

Adding a newline doesn't create any issue here.

I've tried your `pod.yaml` and got the following error:

```
$ helm install .
Error: release pilfering-pronghorn failed: Pod "app" is invalid: spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[0].mountPath: Invalid value: "test": must be an absolute path
```

which means that `mountPath` of `volumeMounts` should be something like `/mnt`.

So, the following `pod.yaml` works pretty good and creates a pod with the exact resources we defined in `values.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: app
  labels:
    app: app
spec:
  containers:
  - name: app
    image: image
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /mnt
        name: test
    resources:
{{ toYaml .Values.pod.resources | indent 6 }}
  volumes:
  - name: test
    emptyDir: {}
```

Comment: Just do `helm template ./` and it's print a empty line between memory and volumes. It's just a example, not a valid template for kubernetes, I just want to show what toYaml add an ampty line

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I guess it is just how `template` works. It shows final template with a new line. My question, why it is worrying you? Finally, it is fully working yaml file and pod is being created successfully.

Comment: to be honest, I thought I was doing something wrong, because when I saw the template I saw empty lines. My opinion is that this is stupefying

Comment: In any case this is not an answer to the question. It is just a "don't worry does no harm", but not an answer to the question.

Comment: @Nickolay when doing scalars in configmaps such as `key: |-<NEWLINE><MULTILINE-VALUE>` trailing spaces and such inside of `<MULTILINE-VALUE>` mess the formatting of the yaml up and make it more difficult to debug things when using `kubectl diff`. Eric's answer down below is useful.

Comment: @CrusaderX IMHO, I think "Eric Nelson" answer is correct. It adheres WYSIWYG. Please consider his answer :)

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me:

```
{{ toYaml .Values.pod.resources | trim | indent 6 }}
```

Answer (score 1):

{{- toYaml .Values.pod.resources | indent 6 -}}

This removes a new line

Answer (score -1):

@Nickolay, it is **not** a valid yaml file, according to helm - at least helm barfs and says:

> error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 51: did not find expected key

For me, line 51 is the empty space - and whatever follows should not be indented to the same level